# Can There be Multiple Result IDs for a Query Operation Result?

Tags: query, bulk-api

When retrieving the result of a batch of a query bulk job, according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm), the following is returned.

```
<result-list xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <result>752x00000004CJE</result>
</result-list>
```

To get the actual results, we have to call the URL *(sfdc)/services/async/48.0/job/jobId/batch/batchId/result/resultId* with the result ID in the above result list.

Is it possible for the result-list to have more than one result ID?

Answer (score 2):

See [How Bulk Queries Are Processed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_bulk_query_processing.htm) for details, but basically, yes, if the result size exceeds 1GB, then they are split in to multiple results, each file being no larger than 1GB each.